# Hide a certain product for a specific customer group or IP

Tags: product, product-collection, permissions, access

I need to hide a certain product for everyone except not for a specific IP (or customer group). This can't be achieved by Magento default. But I was wondering what is the best approach here? Oberserver? Overwrite core collections? I did some research and found [one extension](https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2). I'm not sure if there is a better way do to it. Any ideas are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The Groups Catalog by Vinai is a great extension which I am currently using to achieve similar purpose.

Comment: is it paid or free i.e via github